# Index returning wrong value

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to create a player. My ProcessCreate method is suppose to check the insert index returned from InsertPlayer and display the “successfully created” message if it is not equal to -1 but for some reason it is not returning insert index from insert player as -1. I am not sure on how to fix this and sorry about the long code in advance but I thought it all could be relevant to figure out the problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is the part of my ProcessCreate method that checks for insert player

```
playerindex = InsertPlayer(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);

             if (playerindex != -1)
               {

                 {

                   Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
                   Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
                   players[playerindex].Number, players[playerindex].FirstName, players[playerindex].LastName,
                   players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists, players[playerindex].Points());
                   Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully created!");
                   Console.WriteLine();
                                }

                            }                      

            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

    }
```

> Here is my InsertPlayer and GetInsertIndex method

```
 static Int32 InsertPlayer(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals, 
    Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount)
{
            Int32 insertIndex, shiftCount;
            insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players,ref playerCount);
            for (shiftCount = playerCount; shiftCount > insertIndex; shiftCount--)
                    players[shiftCount] = players[shiftCount - 1];
            try
            {
                players[insertIndex] = new Player(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            playerCount++;
            return insertIndex;
 }
static Int32 GetInsertIndex(Int32 playernumber,Player[] players,
         ref Int32 playerCount)
    {
        Int32 index = 0;
        bool found = false;
        while (index < playerCount && found == false)
            if (players[index].Number > playernumber)
               found = true;
              else
                index++;
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest examining GetInsertIndex and making sure it behaves as you expect.  A little unit testing would help understand where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetInsertIndex()` will always return 0 or greater, meaning your check on `(playerindex != -1)` will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Yes.  And there are some mismatched braces after your if statement (2 before, and 3 after).  I am not sure if that happened when you were pasting into the question.  But that could cause strange results.